# Migrate documents from SP 2010 document library to SP 2013 document library programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, content-migration

I am having 2 environments **SP 2010** & **SP 2013**. Without using any 3rd party tools is it possible to migrate list items, documents,all contents using SP Object Model.

Comment: try this one https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Copy-all-SharePoint-Files-0999c53f#content

Comment: Waqas, Thanks for your reply.I have tried this , but this code  failed when i tried to connect to the SP 2010 site from my SP 2013 environment.

Comment: can i ask why you want to do this programatically? their are other ways i,e manual without using the 3rdparty tools

Answer (score -2):

If you are good at powershell, this is more easy to work with powershell, it takes care of permissions or workflows if any on list as well.

Comment: Shiva can you tell how this can be achieved using PowetShell? These ate 2 different environments.How can I execute powershell on a remote environment? Any sample script available?